# Installation of ibm mq chart version 1.2.0 using helm in Gcp,created a error during pod creation “Creashloopbackoff”

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, ibm-mq, kubernetes-helm

[image: Look at error here]

IBM Mq Helm chart installation failed to create Pod showing "Crashloop Backoff error".

Pod error Message:

> Error setting admin password: /usr/bin/sudo: exit status 1: sudo: effective uid is not 0, is
> /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?

```
Infrastructure: Google Cloud Platform
Kubectl version: 
  Client Version: v1.18.6
  Server Version: v1.16.13-gke.1.
helm chart:
 helm repo add ibm-charts https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IBM/charts/master/repo/stable/
```

**Helm command:**

```
$ helm install mq --set license=accept --set service.type=LoadBalancer --set queueManager.dev.secret.name=mysecret --set queueManager.dev.secret.adminPasswordKey=adminPassword . --set security.initVolumeAsRoot=true
```

Comment: You are using `Google Kubernetes Engine` or `Google Compute Engine` where you created VMs and created cluster using `Kubeadm` or `Minikube` ? Its new cluster or did you have any config there already? Did you follow any tutorial?

Comment: I Started GKE api, Created Kubernetes Cluster with Node pool of 2 nodes

Comment: Isn’t it the same like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63357689/installation-of-ibm-mq-in-gcp-gke-using-helm-charts-had-an-kube-version-error ?

Comment: noo, there i cloned the chart and then install the chart by changing kubeversion Manually. Here im installting the chart directly from repo..

Comment: Could you provide steps to reproduce this issue? You created GKE 1.16.13.1, then add repo `helm repo add ibm-charts https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IBM/charts/master/repo/stable/` then updated repo `helm repo update` and executed helm command? Or there is more steps?

Comment: next Installed Chart by using command: helm install ibm-mq --set license=accept --set service.type=LoadBalancer --set queueManager.dev.secret.name=mysecret --set queueManager.dev.secret.adminPasswordKey=adminPassword . queueManager.dev.adminPassword=Miracle@1234 --set security.initVolumeAsRoot=true

Comment: Then I got an error at Pod level as shown above

Comment: There must be something more. Ive tried to use both commands provided (in comment you probably missed one `--set`) on new cluster. Ive got 
`Error: validation: chart.metadata is required`.

Comment: Try this Command: helm install ibm-mq --set license=accept --set service.type=LoadBalancer --set queueManager.dev.secret.name=mysecret --set queueManager.dev.secret.adminPasswordKey=adminPassword . --set security.initVolumeAsRoot=true

Comment: Still the same. What Helm version are you using? Do you also have `400: Invalid request` while try to reach https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IBM/charts/master/repo/stable/