# Installation of IBM Mq in GCP GKE using helm charts, had an kube version error

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, ibm-mq, kubernetes-helm

[image: error be like]

While I'm trying to install IBM mq in the GCP Kubernetes engine using Helm charts, I got an error as shown in above figure. Anyone help me out from this...

```sh
Infrastructure: Google Cloud Platform
Kubectl version: 
  Client Version: v1.18.6
  Server Version: v1.16.13-gke.1.
Helm version: v3.2.1+gfe51cd1
helm chart:
 helm repo add ibm-charts https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IBM/charts/master/repo/stable/
```

**Helm command:**

```sh
$ helm install mqa ibm-charts/ibm-mqadvanced-server-dev --version 4.0.0 --set license=accept --set service.type=LoadBalancer --set queueManager.dev.secret.name=mysecret --set queueManager.dev.secret.adminPasswordKey=adminPassword --set security.initVolumeAsRoot=true
```

Answer (score 2):

First, it appears it's not installing the right version of the Helm chart. You can follow the official [installation instructions](https://github.com/IBM/charts/tree/master/stable/ibm-mqadvanced-server-dev#installing-the-chart) for the Chart.

Secondly, the messages are inconsistent. The error shows a GKE v1.15.12-gke.2 and also a GKE v1.16.13-gke.1. So I would make sure your client K8s [context](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cluster-access-for-kubectl) is pointing to the right cluster.

It also appears that the kubectl versions are not matching.

For example, you can download the `v1.16.13` client so that it matches (Assuming that your client is on Linux):

```sh
$ curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.16.13/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
$ chmod +x kubectl
$ ./kubectl version
```

✌️

Comment: yeah my client is linux, But it didnt accepting v1.16.13 too......

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

IBM have provided a new sample MQ Helm chart [here](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-helm). Included are a number of samples for different Kubernetes distributions, and GKE can be found [here](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-helm/tree/main/samples/GoogleKubernetesEngine). Worth highlighting that this sample deploys IBM MQ in it Cloud Native high availability topology called NativeHA.